# NIntegrate in mathematica with specific dx rather than machine precision

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integrate

from what I learned in my university and school, numerical integrals are done by chopping a function into rectangles and summing up their areas; so the precision of the integration is defined by the width of each rectangle. The thinner the rectangles are, the better the precision (and the more computational efforts, which is my problem) is required.

I want to do a 3 dimensional NIntegrate over an interpolated function. Which is extremely expensive if I use the default configuration of mathematica. I want to higher the width of the rectangles used in the numerical integral. There are too many options there in mathematica for precision and accuracy and others, but I don't really know which one could do the trick and reduce the computational efforts as best as possible.

Are there options for increasing the integral-rectangles width or something else that would significantly reduce the computation time?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Just a comment on your assumption that Mathematica sums the rectangles: That's a good way to introduce students to integration, but it isn't a very good method.  The trapazoidal rule and Simpson's rule are usually taught as well, but there others.  See the help for `NIntegrate` ffor a list of some of the `Method` options for `NIntegrate`.

Comment: I think all these methods are extremely cheap when down-sampled. I just would like to know what's the cheapest way, computation-wise, to achieve the result I'm looking for. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated the effect of the options `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` or, indeed, any of the other options ?

Comment: The effect in time, is very small. The effect in result I haven't investigated.